# What does ^1 mean in SQL call?

Tags: java, sql, t-sql

```
SELECT LOWER(pla_lan_code) as locale,
    pla_auto_translate_opt_out_flag^1 as autoTranslationEnabled,
    pte_manual_edit_flag^1 as autoTranslated,
    ftr_created_date as queuedDate,
    ftr_translation_date as translationDate,
    ftr_engine as translationEngine,
    ftr_id as translationId,
    pla_auto_translate_opt_out_flag as translationOptOut

SELECT * FROM property_languages (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN properties_text_live (nolock)
```

This query is embedded in Java code. I am trying to convert it into a stored proc. I want to know what ^1 equates to in SQL.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: Even though you did not tell us which DBMS you are using, I'm almost 100% certain that this is documented in the manual of your DBMS. Look for a chapter called "operators" or "functions" or something similar

Answer (score 5):

This isn't standard SQL. In Transact-SQL (used in MS SQL Server and Sybase) `^` is the [bitwise exclusive-OR operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx).

1 ^ 1 is 0, and 0 ^ 1 is 1.

If the original int stores 0 for false and 1 for true, XORing by 1 would reverse the sense of the original flags.

Guessing that pla_auto_translate_opt_out_flag is an int with 1 for opting out and 0 for enabling autotranslation, using the operator returns 1 for enabling and 0 for opting out.